# Get MidColor from UIColor

Tags: ios, uicolor

I was looking for sample which gives me mid colour from passed UIColor. In the following
Example, [Get Slightly Lighter and Darker Color from UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor)
can get lighter & darker colour from UIColor. 
But i need to get average/ mid colour from UIColor.

Anyone help me to solve this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by mid color?

Comment: neither dark nor light colour..middle colour i want

Comment: Explain it with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to which you point steps the colour up or down by 0.2 in the first code example and adjusts brightness in the second.

By mid-colour I assume you mean one of two things: (1) the colour itself, or (2) something that isn't quite as light or quite as dark as the example code. To achieve the latter, all you need to do is change the brightness multiplier, e.g.

```
@implementation UIColor (LightAndDark)

- (UIColor *)lighterColor
{
    CGFloat h, s, b, a;
    if ([self getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a])
        return [UIColor colorWithHue:h
                          saturation:s
                          brightness:MIN(b * 1.15, 1.0)
                               alpha:a];
    return nil;
}

- (UIColor *)darkerColor
{
    CGFloat h, s, b, a;
    if ([self getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a])
        return [UIColor colorWithHue:h
                          saturation:s
                          brightness:b * 0.85
                               alpha:a];
    return nil;
}
@end
```

or is it that you are looking for a colour between two colours? Working on this now will edit again shortly.

**Update: to get middle colour use:**

```
- (UIColor *)betweenColor:(UIColor *)c andColor:(UIColor *)d
{
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    CGFloat r2, g2, b2, a2;
    [c getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    [d getRed:&r2 green:&g2 blue:&b2 alpha:&a2];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(r + r2)/2
                           green:(g + g2)/2
                            blue:(b + b2)/2
                           alpha:a];
    return nil;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
UIColor *midColor = [self betweenColor:[UIColor whiteColor] andColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.view.backgroundColor = midColor;
```

and here's the HSB midpoint:

```
- (UIColor *)betweenColor:(UIColor *)c andColor:(UIColor *)d
{
    CGFloat h, s, b, a;
    CGFloat h2, s2, b2, a2;
    [c getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];
    [d getHue:&h2 saturation:&s2 brightness:&b2 alpha:&a2];
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:(h+h2)/2
                      saturation:(s+s2)/2
                      brightness:(b+b2)/2
                           alpha:a];    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Yes i m also  following same way.. but not getting expected result.       -(UIColor *)middleColorForColor:(UIColor *)iColor {
    
    CGFloat h, s, b, a;
    UIColor *midColor = nil;
    
    if ([iColor getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a])
        
        midColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:h
                          saturation:s
                          brightness:b * 0.65
                               alpha:a];
    
    
    [self.middleColorView setBackgroundColor:midColor];

    return midColor;
}

Comment: If i send darkest & lightest colour, is it possible to get average colour?

Comment: Was it one of these solutions or something else? If something else please share.

Comment: Yes between colour method u wrote know.. same way. I am taking average for RGB values :)