# Objective-c : How to create different shades of a color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Is there any algorithm that will create different shades for given Hex or RGB value? I have tried with alpha increasing & decreasing but it's not looking good with light colors(ex: white color).

[image]

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor)?

Comment: use `HBS` instead or `RGB`, and you can play with the `brightness`, but please do not create another fifty shades of grey.

Comment: @holex : thank you so much for your suggestion(play with brightness). It is working .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to do this is using HSB colour space.

It's how I did the left hand section of the keyboard in my latest app...

[image]

The "shade" of the colour is the `H` value and `S` value. You can then change the brightness of it by adjusting the `B` value.

So if you had a colour like...

[HSB - 0.5, 0.9, 0.9](http://hslpicker.com/#cffcfc) - very light blue

You could create darker shades by changing the B value...

[HSB - 0.5, 0.9, 0.3](http://hslpicker.com/#089191) - dark blue of the same shade.

Create HSB colours like...

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.5 saturation:0.9 brightness:0.4 alpha:1.0];
```

In my app I had a "lightest brightness" and a "darkest brightness".

The I worked out the change in brightness for each section by dividing the difference between them by the number of sections.

Using a `for` loop I was able to easily create the different section colours.

Comment: While this is a good answer, the link to your app bugs me a little. Seems a screenshot would have been enough, more "future proof" and less gratuitous self-promoting.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis edited. Hey, we all have to get word out there somehow :P edited now though.