# How to set a calculated color value to UITableViewController Programmatically using Swift?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, rgb

[image]

For example I'm trying to make a tableViewController that has a color value for each row. According to the index, the color will be from bright to dark. I was mentioned that it can be done in a few lines of code, but I'm confused how to do it.

Answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c : How to create different shades of a color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260727/objective-c-how-to-create-different-shades-of-a-color)

Comment: This question is almost identical. The same code can be used here too. The change is instead of using a for loop to vary the colour you just need to use the index (and the number of rows).

Comment: if ()
        {
            cell!.colorImage.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.4, saturation: 0.4, brightness: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        }

Comment: Not so sure how to have it change in value.